# How to add new year?

Tags: coldfusion, dateadd

I would like to increment school year every time after previous school year is over. For example my current code looks like this:

```
WHERE schooldt BETWEEN '07/01/2016' AND '06/30/2017'
```

So once school year is over `06/30/2017` I would like to set new start date and new end date automatically. I was thinking about using dateAdd() in cold fusion. Is there any other way to do this and what would be the most efficient?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know when the school starts next year? Does it always start on the 1st July and ends on the 30th June?

Comment: Yes always will start on 07/01 and end on 06/30. So I want to increment my start year and my end year after school year ends.

Comment: The rest of the query is relevant.  Please post it.

Comment: @DanBracuk I do not have any problems or questions about my query. Only question is how and what is the best way to increment start and end year after previous school year is over.

Comment: Your question includes, `Is there any other way to do this and what would be most efficient?`.  That's why the rest of the query is relevant.

Comment: The better question is exactly what is your end goal here? Why do you need to increment the school year? There may be a much better overall solution to your full problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to increment school year every time after previous school year is over

Then implement logic that changes the date values used in your query based on the current month. If the current month is earlier than July, then you know the current school year is still in progress. So deduct one year to calculate the start date. Otherwise, move to the next year.

```
    <cfset today = now()>
    <!--- If the current school year is still in progress --->
    <cfif month(today) lt 7>
        <cfset startDate = createDate( year(today) - 1, 7, 1)>
        <cfset endDate = createDate( year(today), 6, 30)>
    <!--- Otherwise, move to next year --->
    <cfelse>
        <cfset startDate = createDate( year(today), 7, 1)>
        <cfset endDate = createDate( year(today) + 1, 6, 30)>
    </cfif>
```

As far as querying, two things to keep in mind:

- Date strings are ambiguous. Always use date objects instead.
- Be careful with date comparisons and the `BETWEEN` operator. If the `SchoolDt` column contained both a date and time, the result may not be what you expected. A more flexible construct (that stills works even if a column contains both date and time) is:

  ```
  WHERE SchoolDt >= <cfqueryparam value="#startDate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
  AND   SchoolDt < <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1, endDate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
  ```

  If you are using [new Query()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/script-functions-implemented-as-cfcs/query.html), parameterize the sql string and use `addParam` instead:

  ```
  yourQuery.addParam( name="startDate"
                     , value="#startDate#"
                     , cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" );

  yourQuery.addParam( name="endDate"
                     , value="#endDate#"
                     , cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" );
  ```

Comment: Thank you! This works excellent, I used dateFormat() around create date. I'm not sure if that's something that can change the logic above.

Comment: @espresso_coffee - No, do not use dateFormat() because it converts the date *objects* into strings (which are ambiguous). DateFormat is only for presentation, ie when you need to display human friendly values to users. When working with databases (or using date functions) leave the values as date objects.

Comment: Thanks again. If I use this to run my query <cfset test = new query()>
<cfset test.setAttributes( datasource = testDB, sql = trim(ArrayToList(qString, " ")))>
<cfset moveIn = test.execute().getResult()> Do I have to use cfqueryparam inside of ArrayAppend()?

Comment: No idea what the array functions have to do with your db queries ;-) However, If you are using cfscript, you should definitely be using `addParam` (ie cfscript version of `cfqueryparam`) in your queries.

Comment: Why use CF to find the date range? I hate date logic to begin with, but I'd suggest keeping it as close to the actual question as possible: do it in the database. Or even better yet, if you're needing date logic like this, chances are a pre-populated calendar table would be very useful to you. Then you could set up all sorts of date logic without having to do keep figuring out what school year you're supposed to be in.

Comment: And +1 for "Be careful with date comparisons and the BETWEEN operator."

Comment: @Shawn - For two reasons A) I do not really see a big advantage to using db functions - in this *specific* case. It is unlikely to be achieved with a one-liner and I am not a big fan of using complex logic (ie if/else, declare, etcetera) in cfquery's. That is better wrapped in a stored proc IMO B) It is simpler to illustrate the proper concepts in CF ;-) However, I definitely agree this could be a good use for a calendar table. I have not given it much thought, so if you have a specific structure in mind, feel free to post it as an answer. That would be good info to have in the archives.

Comment: Honestly, if it's at all possible, just add and calc a school year integer to the database. Then filter on that school year.

Answer (score 2):

For the date table answer:

```
CREATE TABLE calendar ( 
    SeqNum int
    , schooldt date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , theYear int
    , theMonth tinyint
    , theDay tinyint
    , schoolyear int
    , isSchoolDay tinyint   /* Can count schooldays */ 
    , isHoliday tinyint /* Can count holidays. */
)

DECLARE @StartDate date = '1/1/2010'

/* Build tally table with 10^x rows */
; WITH TallyTable (x) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(x)       -- 10 days
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(x) -- 100 days
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(x) -- 1000 days
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(x) -- 10000 days
)
INSERT INTO calendar ( SeqNum, schooldt, theYear, theMonth, theDay, schoolyear, isSchoolDay, isHoliday )
SELECT 
    tt.x AS SeqNum
    , d1.theDate
    , d2.theYear
    , d2.theMonth
    , d2.theDay
    , d2.theSchoolYear
    , 1 , 0 /* Defaults for isSchoolDay and isHoliday. Add if needed. */
FROM TallyTable tt
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT theDate = DATEADD(dd, (tt.x-1), @StartDate) /* Starting date */
) d1
CROSS APPLY 
(  
    SELECT  theYear = DATEPART(yy,d1.theDate)
        , theMonth = DATEPART(mm,d1.theDate)
        , theDay = DATEPART(dd,d1.theDate) 
        , theSchoolYear = CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm,d1.theDate) < 7 THEN DATEPART(yyyy,d1.theDate) ELSE DATEPART(yyyy,d1.theDate)+1 END
) d2;
```

Something along those lines will give you a list of days for several years out. Then you can join on this table to get the range that you want.

To improve the table, you can include information to label Holidays and Weekends, so that you only see days that school is actually in session. And most importantly, you can filter it all by the current school year that you wish to see. You don't have to worry about incrementing the school year when it's time to change.

But it again begs the question, what is your ultimate goal of this query? There may be even better ways to accomplish your ultimate goal.